# How do I stop vs code to stop debugging internal cpp modules?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[VScode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMlZO.jpg)

Vscode cpp debugger is taking me in to internal c++ modules like you can see in this picture
I just want it to debug my files

Comment: try `"justMyCode": true` in the debug configuration

Comment: but by launch.json is empty

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create new file `launch.json` first.

Now add

```json
{
  "name": "C++ Launch (Windows)",
  "type": "cppvsdbg",
  "justMyCode": true,
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "C:\\app1\\Debug\\app1.exe",
  "symbolSearchPath": "C:\\Symbols;C:\\SymbolDir2",
  "externalConsole": true,
  "logging": {
    "moduleLoad": false,
    "trace": true
  },
  "visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/my.natvis",
  "showDisplayString": true
}
```

Check this first: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

If above thing doesn't work, try using "Step Over" option when you hit internal C++ functions. 
Check this:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions